# activate the toggle on one button at a time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have this code taken from bootstrap: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/button#pressed-state-and-toggling

```
<template>
<div>
 <b-button-group size="sm">
  <b-button
    v-for="(btn, idx) in buttons"
    :key="idx"
    :pressed.sync="btn.state"
    variant="primary"
  >
    {{ btn.caption }}
  </b-button>
 </b-button-group>
 <p>Pressed States: <strong>{{ btnStates }}</strong></p>
 </div>
</template>

 <script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         buttons: [
           { caption: 'Toggle 1', state: true },
           { caption: 'Toggle 2', state: false },
           { caption: 'Toggle 3', state: false },
           { caption: 'Toggle 4', state: false }
         ]
       }
     },
     computed: {
       btnStates() {
         return this.buttons.map(btn => btn.state)
       }
     }
   }
 </script>
```

I would like the toggle to work on a single element, i.e. only one can be `true`. 
So when you click on an element it becomes `true` but if there are others already `true` they must become `false`. 
In a nutshell, only one button must be active and no more. 
It seemed an easy thing, the problem arises as the click component has a focus that when you click anywhere else on the screen goes away, and therefore is not really active.

Comment: Are you asking about the toggle or the focus?

Comment: both of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the only-one functionality with a `click` handler that uses the index of the button clicked.  The handler will unpress all of the other buttons.

```html
<b-button
   v-for="(btn, idx) in buttons"
   :key="idx"
   :pressed.sync="btn.state"
   variant="primary"
   @click="onPress(idx)"
>
```

```js
methods: {
  onPress(i) {
    this.buttons.forEach((b, index) => b.state = i === index)
  }
}
```

The loss of focus doesn't actually change any of the buttons' pressed state, it only loses the visual focus border.

[image]